# I would like an explanation of each package in package list

Tags: package-management

I know that entering

```
dpkg --get-selections "*" >pkg.list
```

gives a listing of the packages, but I would also like a brief explanation/description of what each of those packages does.  Is there a way to generate such a description?

Answer (score 2):

My thought for SO many packages would be first to create a variable with them:

The following will create the **packages** variable and assign all packages that dpkg outputs.
`packages=$(dpkg --get-selections '*' | grep 'install' | cut -f1)`

You can further limit this by adding an additional grep at the end, for example:

`packages=$(dpkg --get-selections '*' | grep 'install' | cut -f1| grep 'wine')`

will output all **wine** packages. This is only if you want to only see a specific package.

After this we then use FOR to start parsing all packages in the "packages" variable:

`for pack in $packages ; do apt-cache showpkg $pack; done`

This will give us a LOT of information for each package found. If you are a fan of **aptitude** then you can use aptitude to show the information in a more human friendly way:

`for pack in $packages ; do aptitude show $pack; done`

If you are happy with the output you can further output this into a file:

`for pack in $packages ; do aptitude show $pack >> packages.txt; done`

A copy/paste version of all of this would be:

APTITUDE Version

`packages=$(dpkg --get-selections '*' | grep 'install' | cut -f1)`
`for pack in $packages ; do aptitude show $pack; done`

APT-GET Version

`packages=$(dpkg --get-selections '*' | grep 'install' | cut -f1)`
`for pack in $packages ; do apt-cache showpkg $pack; done`

If you do all packages, it will take some time for them to be included in the file as output.